# Can Macs connect to VPNs with MS-CHAPv2?

Tags: mac, network, vpn

I've been provided directions with how to connect to a VPN on a remote server, but it's just one of those simple "Connect to network, VPN, etc." wizards from Microsoft Windows that establishes a VPN over the WAN Miniport interface. I can connect just fine on Windows.

However, how would I go about this on a mac? I've tried configuring a VPN through the network preferences, but there's no settings anywhere to specify MS-CHAPv2, so authentication fails using all other methods that Mac supports.

Is there any way that I could get this working? I've been looking online but can't really find anything solid. Do I need to find some random VPN client or something that supports this? A little annoyed and stumped here and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I found [an answer](https://superuser.com/questions/608946/force-ms-chapv2-vpn-connection-from-mac) over on Superuser that seems to involve some work in the terminal. Certainly not an ideal solution...

Comment: Thanks. I tried this suggestion but after being prompted for my password and entering it, it just goes back to the command line prompt.

Comment: it doesn't work anymore